# How to add (Please Wait) screen or popUp to the system while the system is sending an email after clicking on the Finished button in the Wizard?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I was using an ASP.NET Wizard control for adding new users to the web-based application that I developed. Everything works well and fine. Now, I got a new requirement from the Admin of the system which is sending an email notification to the new user telling him that he has been added to the system. I added the Mail function to my code and it works. Now, after clicking on the Finished button on the Wizard, the user will be added to the database and the system will send an email notification to the user, then the wizard will show me the Success message. However, sometimes it takes a long time until the system sending that email to the user and the wizard showing me the Success message.

**So How I can display a (Please Wait ) screen/PopUp during the time that the system is working on sending that email to the user?**

**Code-Behind with Mail function:**

```
 protected void Wizard1_FinishButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        string username = TextBox1.Text;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(radio1.SelectedValue) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            string connString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True";

            string insertUserCommand = "INSERT INTO employee (Name, Username, JobTitle, BadgeNo, EmpOrgType, DivisionCode) values (@Name, @Username, @JobTitle, @BadgeNo, @EmpOrgType, @DivisionCode)";
            string cmdText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM employee WHERE Username = '" + username + "'";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                // Open DB connection.
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
                {
                    if ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 0){

                        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(insertUserCommand, conn);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", user.Name);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobTitle", jobTitle);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BadgeNo", EmpNo.));
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpOrgType", orgType);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DivisionCode", orgCode);
                        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                }
            }

            //For updating the role of the user
            string deleteCommand = "DELETE FROM UserRole where Username=@Username";
            string insertCommand = "INSERT INTO UserRole (RoleID,Username) values(@RoleID,@Username)";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                //using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(deleteCommand, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    //Now the insert
                    cmd.CommandText = insertCommand;
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear(); 
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleID", radio1.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    //infoSpan.InnerText = String.Format("The users role has been updated to - {0}", radio1.SelectedValue);
                    //cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    //infoSpan.InnerText = String.Format("The users role has been updated to - {0}", radio1.SelectedValue);
                }
            }

            Wizard1.Visible = false;
            wizard.InnerHtml = @"<p><b>The task has been done successfully.</b> <br /> <a href='UserManagement.aspx'>Edit Another User</a></p>";
        }

        SendEmailToUser(username);

    }
/*****************************************************/


    protected void SendNotificationByEmail(string toAddresses, string fromAddress, string MailSubject, string MessageBody, bool isBodyHtml)
    {
        SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("MailAddress");
        try
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress("test@mailAddress.com", "Test Sys");


            msg.Bcc.Add(toAddresses);
            msg.Subject = MailSubject;
            msg.Body = MessageBody;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;
            sc.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }

    protected void Send(string username)
    {
        string connString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True";

        string networkID = username.ToString();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            var sbEmailAddresses = new System.Text.StringBuilder(2000);

            //initiate the varibles that will be retreived from the database
            string name = null;

            // Open DB connection.
            conn.Open();

            string cmdText2 = @"SELECT     Name
                                FROM       dbo.employee
                                WHERE     (Username = @networkID)";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText2, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@networkID", networkID);
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                        sbEmailAddresses.Append(username).Append("@mailAddress.com");
                    }
                }

                //var sEMailAddresses = sbEmailAddresses.ToString();
                string body = @"...........................";
                SendNotificationByEmail(sbEmailAddresses.ToString(), "", "Welcome...", body, true);
                sbEmailAddresses.Clear();
                reader.Close();


            }

            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This kind of tasks are usually executed on the background, my recommendation is simply show a message to the user: "Your process is being processed, we will contact you via email soon" or similar. If you keep going with your current design I think you will eventually face scalability issues, since you would be blocking the application.

Comment: Since I am a new ASP.NET developer, could you please tell me how I can develop the sending email function as a background method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application uses an `UpdatePanel`, you can use the [`UpdateProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updateprogress.aspx) control to show whatever you want while the request is processing.